# If I look up Mars in the nightsky for one second, can I see photons from perseverance rover?

Tags: optics, photons, everyday-life, estimation

The classical EM theory would say that yes, of course, there is a small EM amplitude wave that comes from the rover which would end up in my retina, at any time interval of the observation.

However I do not know what the answer is, according to deeper theories (quantum field theory?), where light is quantized as photons. If the answer is ''probably not'', can we have an estimate on this probability? What would be the expected time of observation such that the probabilty of a retina to catch at least one photon from perseverance to yield 1/2?

My intuition tells me that the probability is very low, and that an observer would have to wait thousands of years before a single photon from the rover would end on his retina. I base my intuition on the difficulty to measure a single photon coming from a laser on earth pointing towards a mirror on the Moon, where in this case the photon beam is much better oriented than in the case of perseverance, and the proximity is also much greater in the Moon's case.

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: Maybe you can model the rover as a 2-square-meter diffuse surface with 100% reflectivity.  Then you can take the peak solar irradiance on that surface, calculate the total reflected light treated as emanating from a Lambertian point, and do the 1/R^2 irradiance at your eyeball estimate

Comment: And then there's the fact that atmospheric distortion can make the photon hit a rod not really associated with the direction of Mars, or that a single photon hitting the retina doesn't really translate to a human "seeing" something. But yes, best to start with the simple order of magnitude calculations.

Comment: @Qmechanic no, I am not sure how to deal with the number of photons. I can imagine that the rover would shine/reflect say 400 W per square meter, of EM radiation. I can imagine the black body spectrum (assuming it reflects the solar light without distortion), but where do I implement the number of photons?

Comment: Ah I think I see how. Yeah the blackbody distribution of energy should be translated to number of photons yielding 400 W or something like that. But I am quite confused, as I have read that I cannot rely on these distributions. For example that max (peak) in the wavelength spectrum does not match the max in frequency spectrum if I use the relation $\nu = \lambda/c$. So I am still lost.

Comment: @AccidentalBismuthTransform  Don't use black-body. Just, for first-order, consider the rover to be 100% reflective, Lambertian diffuse, and use the solar insolation to determine the amount of reflected energy

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I imagine it, to first order, as a 400 W point source radiating in the half sphere towards the Earth (say Mars is illuminated as viewed on Earth). So the 400 W are spread to a surface of $2\pi r^2$ where $r \approx 225000000 km^2$. Say the eye entry (pupil) is a disk of 0.5 cm of diameter, so a surface area of $pi *0.025cm^2$. So I can now easily get the power that enters the eye when Mars is about 225 mllion km away (it's just the ratio of these 2 disproportionate area, times 400 W). But this doesn't help me an iota where I am stuck, namely in introducing the photons number.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have a better answer for you. Imagine a sphere of the photos that are reflected from the perseverance rover expanding out into space. If you can find out the surface area of that expansive sphere, your eye's radius, and the number of photos that pass through the total surface, you can find out how many are hitting your eye.

The closest approach of Mars to earth is 54.6 million km. That is the radius of the sphere. Surface area of a sphere is 4(pi)(R)^2 where R is your radius of the sphere. 54.6 million km to meters is 54600000000 meters, or 5.46E10 meters. 4(pi)(5.46 x 10^10 m)^2 = 3.75E22 m^2.

Assuming the area available for photons to enter your eye is 1 cm^2, then the area in meters is 1E-4 m. The ratio of the area of your eyeball to the surface of the sphere is about 2.67E-27. In other words, 2.67E-27 photons will hit your eyeball per second per 1 photon that is going through that larger sphere.

Next, we need to find out how many photons are reflected by the rover. At local noon on Mars, with Sun directly overhead, the solar irradiance is 590W/m^2 (590 watts per square meter).

I found this thread on Quora to find the number of photons. I just adapted the numbers a little bit.
https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-no-of-photons-per-second-by-a-lamp-emitting-10-watts-power-and-having-wavelength-550-nanometer

Since 550 nm for wavelength is right in the middle of the spectrum for visible light, lets assume that all of the photons have a wavelength of 550nm.

550 nm photons have 2.26 eV.

eV = 1.6×10−19 joules

3.62x10–19 joules per photon 550nm

590W = 590 joules per second.

590W/(550nm joules per photon)=1.81E21 photons per second at 590W.

If we multiply 1.81E21 photons per second by the top surface area of Perseverance, then we have the number of photons that are coming off of Perseverance per second. The top surface area is about 8 meters squared, so now we have 1.45E22 photons.

If we multiply the total amount of photons emmited by the ratio of photons that will hit your eye to the total surface area of the expanding sphere, we get 0.0000386515608 photons per second. Because you have two eyes, that number is 0.0000773031216 that are entering your eyes per second. After multiplying that number by the ratio of second to minutes (60) and minutes to hours (60) we can conclude that you will see a photon that hit perseverance every 4 hours.

So, in theory, yes, you could have a photon hit your eye if you stare at Mars long enough. But, its certainly not practical. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for a first shot on the answer. There are some inconsistencies in your calculation, which should resolve as soon as you add proper units to the 'proportional intensity' (and the other numbers which don't have a unit yet).

Comment: I use [PhyxCalc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phyxcalc/) for these kind of calculations.

Comment: Uh? How does this answer the question? Sure, there is a certain non zero number of photons emitted, but then so what? How does this imply that some of them will end in a retina over the course of 1s?

Comment: Nice start!  Now ya need to consider the spectral power distribution of that 590 W and convolve that with they eye's scotopic response https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotopic_vision  .  Most of the photons are outside our retina's response range.

Comment: Come to think of it,  rather obviously we can see the entire Mars disk, which puts a nice lower bound on things.  Since there's no chance at all of resolving the Rover vs the scene background (spatially),  we might detect Rover photons without any way of knowing they came from it rather than Mars' surface

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am editing the post to make it much better.